# How to check if the input is negative?

Tags: c, integer

The program receives an account number from the user and it cannot be negative.

Is there any other way to check if it is negative?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int account = 0;
        
    printf("Enter your account number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &account);
        
    while(account<0)
    {
        printf("Error: Enter a valid account number.\n");
        scanf("%d", &account);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of account?

Comment: the type is int @wobr

Comment: Can you post a complete program? With `#include ..` and `int main()` and so? And then also the exact numbers, which will produce the error?

Comment: The only completely certain way is to read a string and make sure it's composed of characters '0' to '9' only (and possibly ENTER or other whitespace), then convert that string to a value with, for example, `strtoul()`

Comment: @mch I am trying but they do not allow me. Program is too long.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, the full example is ~4 lines larger than your snippet: `#include <stdio.h>` `int main()` `{` and `}`. Can you at least add the numbers, which produce the error?

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve (maybe because you keep changing the question), your program does what is supposed to do. Now you are asking if there is any other way to check for a negative number but removed the mention of it not working, what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altough the question doesn't provide the example inputs causing the behavior you notice, you are probably experiencing **overflow** issues.

`int` type,  in most modern machine swhere it is stored using 4 bytes, can represent integers from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. If you provide a value greater than the maximum positive number (`INT_MAX`) the value would require a bigger number of bytes to be stored, so in the one actually stored the information of the most significant bits is lost, and the resulting value might end up in the negative range. The same can happen also for big negative values.

What you can do is using *long integers* so that 8 bits are used and the range is bigger: from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.

```
long num;
scanf ("%ld", &num);
```

What I would like to emphatize is that numbers representation in computers will always be limited whatever is the number of bytes you use. If these limits are not ok for your application requirements you will have to change your approach, either

- using [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), which warns you with a proper return value if an overflow or underflow occurs
- acquiring the whole string and parsing it yourself

Comment: Makes sense now! The program is not expected to receive very long numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can only read `char` from user input safely, so you need to read `char *` then convert them to an other type. For your problem you can do this:

```c
char account_str[MAX_CHAR];
unsigned int account = 0;
bool check = false;

printf("Enter your account number:\n");
do
{
    fgets(account_str, MAX_CHAR, stdin); // read the account number (as string)
    check = isPosNumStr(account_str);
    // isPosNumStr is a personal function that determine if a string have only
    // digit and is positive
    if (!check) {
        printf("Error: Enter a valid account number.\n"); 
    }
} while (!check)
account = atoi(account_str); // convert string to int
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* For the account number you should use a "long" instead a "int", 
And this happens because the account number needs a bigger allocation of memory.
I recomend you to look for "int" limits to understand this.*/

long NumbAccount;

void main(){
    printf("Enter your account number:\n");
scanf("%ld", &NumbAccount);

while(NumbAccount<0)
{
    printf("Error: Enter a valid account number.\n");
    scanf("%ld", &NumbAccount);
}
}
```

Comment: I can only use integers though. I only need to check for negative numbers

Comment: @JoanaF `long` variables ARE integers.

Comment: you are using `scanf("%ld", &NumbAccount);` in the first input but `scanf("%d", &NumbAccount);` in the second. It should probably be `%ld` in both  if you wanna go with `long`

Comment: @JohnDoe, I've forgot to put "%ld" in the second scanf, thanks for your correction

Comment: Why did you change the correct `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` from the question to the incorrect `void main()` in your answer?

Comment: @mch to be honest, I'm new in C, I understood the problem of Joana, but still didn't understand what does those parameters inside the main, and because of that I used void main()